# Jquery remove hash from url, after going to section

Tags: jquery

I have this page here:

http://raidersleafs.com/andreaparliamentlaw/professional-development.html

If you click on one of the menu items at the top, lets say 'Business Law'

it will redirect to here:

http://raidersleafs.com/andreaparliamentlaw/index.html#business

The correct section of the site, but I am looking to remove the `#busness` in the URL, while still going to that section. I have tried `window.location.hash=""` and that works, but it does not brings me to the top of the site instead of the section business law....I hope this makes sense, and is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Yeah... this is a normal behavior... Just prevent de default behavior ... ? But the hask is recommended to link that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
y = window.scrollY; 
window.location.hash=""; 
window.scrollTo(0, y);
```

Which gets the current scroll position, changes the hash, then scrolls back to where it was before.

Or you could do it like this:

```
history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

which will get rid of the `#` at the end of the URL as well, and then you don't have to mess with the scroll position.

Comment: Hey, I tried both of your solutions, the first one still has the # in the URL and does not scroll and the second removes the # completely, but does not goto the section

Comment: you are running this after the page has loaded, right? `$(window).on('load', function() { history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname); });`